# Testing WebScrape in Selenium python without running whole script?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

this may be a very basic question but I'm practicing web scraping a dynamic page with Selenium and I wanted to know if there was a way to only test just the web scraping of a table portion without having to run the whole code? Am I being a noob and just not seeing what I'm doing wrong? As I have many delays in my code to prevent errors when using selenium to click through buttons and sign in to get to the page where the table is to scrape. But it takes a lot of time as I test my web scrape over and over to constantly wait for the whole script to run.

Comment: You need to give some details(in terms of code, examples). This is more of an opinion-based question.

Comment: By delays in your code do you mean something like `time.sleep()`? - you can use the `webdriver.wait` which is way more efficient - [selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), it may make your code run faster, also give more details please

Comment: @xtekky i've created a delay as such. `def delay(): time.sleep(random.randint(2,3))` Then I use this to give time for selenium to let webpages load and in between clicks so it doesn't go to fast for an error.

Comment: This is not optimized at all, definitely consider adding webdriver.wait - [youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/5HROcdUrQAM), if you want, you can share the full script, i'll take a look at it

Comment: @xtekky I've attached the script

Comment: @OrbitDuster How the frick are you going to solve the captcha, it is going to be very hard, unless you do it by hand, I am taking a look at your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `webdriver.wait` to your script and simplified it.

Note that you have to import `WebDriverWait` and `expected_conditions as EC`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver.get("webpage")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

enter_username = input('Enter Username: ')
enter_password = input('Enter Password: ')

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"UserName"))).send_keys(enter_username) #userbox
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"Password"))).send_keys(enter_password) #password

driver.switch_to.default_content()

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"btn-primary"))).click() #email box
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"portlet"))).click() #smart search box
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"Search"))).send_keys("Search Results") #search box


try:
    #Code to click captcha checkbox
    #Code to solve recaptcha
except:
    print("Recaptcha did not appear")
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"Submit"))).click() #submit box

#def save_Search_Results():
try:
    ***#BeautfiulSoup data This is where I'm testing to save data****
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks this is speeding up the code for testing and not hitting any errors along the way.

Comment: @OrbitDuster Glad it's working, just tell me if there any are any errors or you have any questions